# SVG design rules for overlapping items

Tags: svg

Stack Overflow Meta is discussing an [issue about the favorite star](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306325/the-yellow-star-in-the-sprites-svg-image-looks-unfinished).

As we can see in high zoom rates, there is an unfilled area. Looking even closer, you can find more issues, e.g. that the whole outline is not symmetrical.

[image: Yellow favorite question star]

To me, I'd never have designed the star like this anyway. Instead I'd

- take a copy of the star,
- resize it,
- put the larger one in the background

Is there any reason my approach would result in "bad" SVG? Is there a SVG rule unknown to me that objects should not overlap?

My approach would at least require less points, thus be potentially smaller in size and easier to calculate for a computer (faster), doesn't it?

Comment: I'd just set the line color different from the fill color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there would be no issue with your approach. SVG elements are implicitly rendered in the other that they appear in the document, the [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#RenderingOrder)

As long as the first (larger) star appeared first, the second would be drawn over it without any issues.

(For this particular drawing though, a simpler  approach with less nodes would be to draw one star with a wider stroke to represent the outer border.)

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the shape once stroke is added or run simplify. Then export 100% vector svg. The problem here is that nobody learns pathfinder. People often treat illustrator like photoshop it’s and use layer stacks instead of grouping